# How can I output "console.write"-style output (no newline) with NLog?

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

How can I output log as `console.write()` i.e. no newline **with [NLog](http://www.nlog-project.org/)**?

`${message}` defaults to inserting a newline.

Comment: could you please explain more?

Comment: I think he means when using nlog

Comment: yes i mean  With NLog , i've read the document , but i can't find the layout like 'console.write'-like  output !

Answer (score 1):

The filetarget has the property `LineEnding` which could be set to the following values:

- `Default` - Insert platform-dependent end-of-line sequence after each line.
- `CR` - Insert CR character (ASCII 13) after each line.
- `CRLF` - Insert CR LF sequence (ASCII 13, ASCII 10) after each line.
- `LF` - Insert LF character (ASCII 10) after each line.
- `None` - Don't insert any line ending.

In your case you need `None`, so:

```
 <target xsi:type="File"
          name="file1"
          lineEnding="None"
```

If you need this in another target, e.g. ConsoleTarget, then that isn't implemented. Please [open an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the replace new lines layout renderer in your nlog config e.g.:

```
<target name="HealthLog" 
    xsi:type="File" 
    fileName="$C:\Logs\logfile.log"
    layout="${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss.fff} ${level:uppercase=true} ${replace-newlines:${message}}"
/>
```

Documentation on the replace new lines layout renderer can be found here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Replace-NewLines-Layout-Renderer

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your meaning, it seems that you have new line characters in the string you want to write which causes it to go to the new line in the console, if so replace the newline characters with blank string like below.

```
string Message = "testMessage\r\n";
Console.Write(Message.Replace("\r\n",""));
```

Comment: +1, this was what I was going to answer with when I read the question.

Comment: A nice guess, but s/he wants to output with something like "myNlogLogger.Info("This is a log message");". I don't know that NLog provides the capability to omit the newline.

Comment: This was actually what I was searching for, but as mentioned does not really answer the question.  Thx

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a property named [LineEndingMode / LineEnding](https://github.com/november06/NLog/blob/master/src/NLog/Targets/LineEndingMode.cs), which you could try to modify.

Answer (score -1):

To log items in the console, use console.log(item).