# Formatting Console Output for Multi-Line Data

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm not too sure how to technically word what I'm trying to do so the title may be somewhat vague.

In short, I'm trying to output data into the console to be formatted as multiple lines individually, but overall still run as a "single line".

As an example, I'm trying to write "99A" and "42B" to the console so that it appears as:

```
94
92
AB
```

But what I've been able to do is only:

```
9
9
A
4
2
B
```

So I can format my data correctly, but can't get it to Write or WriteLine in the manner that I want. I will eventually turn this to write into a file but for figuring this out console should do.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699294/how-can-i-output-console-write-style-output-no-newline-with-nlog - might help

Comment: @Lauzerk, please share your code so that i can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a C# translation of a Java answer by [**RoToRa**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/2035/rotora) to a similar question on [**Code Review**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/46630):

```
using System;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    printVertical("99A 42B");
  }

  public static void printVertical(string sentence) {
    string[] words = sentence.Split(' ');

    bool allWordsEnded;
    int row = 0;

    do {
      allWordsEnded = true;

      char[] output = new char[words.Length * 2];
      int column = 0;
      foreach(String word in words) {
        char c;
        if (row < word.Length) {
          c = word[row];
          allWordsEnded = false;
        } else {
          c = ' ';
        }
        output[column++] = c;
      }
      if (!allWordsEnded) {
        Console.WriteLine(output);
      }
      row++;
    }
    while (!allWordsEnded);
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
94
92
AB
```